# Creating slicer in VBA and changeing style

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

It is a large workbook with many sheets so all the names need to be variable.

This is what I have:

```vb
Sub TestAddSlicer()
    var_Pivot_Name = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).Name
    var_Slicer_Name = "Booking Status " + var_Pivot_Name
    var_SlicerCache_Name = "SlicerCache " + var_Pivot_Name
    var_Slicer_Source = "fld_Participation_Status"
    'Add slicer here I get Error "="
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(var_Pivot_Name), var_Slicer_Source,var_SlicerCache_Name).Slicers.Add (ActiveSheet, , var_Slicer_Name, _
    "Booking Status", 185.4, 401.4, 144, 194.25)
    'Color Slicer
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(var_Slicer_Name)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(var_Slicer_Name).Slicers(var_Slicer_Name).Style = "Datenschnittformat 1"
End Sub
```

I had versions where the adding of a slicer worked but the coloring never did.

Answer (score 0):

First, the slicer cache name cannot contain any spaces.  So you can replace the space with an underscore.  Also, it's considered good practice to use the ampersand (&) instead of the plus (+) sign to concatenate values.  So I would suggest that you replace the plus sign with an ampersand.

```
var_SlicerCache_Name = "SlicerCache_" & var_Pivot_Name
```

Secondly, you'll need to remove the brackets from the arguments for `Slicers.add`, and you'll need to remove the blank line as well.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(var_Pivot_Name), var_Slicer_Source, var_SlicerCache_Name).Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , var_Slicer_Name, _
    "Booking Status", 185.4, 401.4, 144, 194.25
```